# VBA Excel - for each range fails

Tags: vba, for-loop, range, each

In the following code, for each range in range is failing. r is not returning a single cell but instead the entire parent range.

I had previously created a class module with a get property called "range". That seemed to be the cause that broke the loop. However I have since removed that module and restarted excel / restarted the computer even. And the loop still fails.

Any ideas?

```
Private Sub GetIters()

    Dim FilterRng       As Range
    Dim ItersRng        As Range
    Dim r               As Range

    Set FilterRng = pFieldRng.Resize(pCountRow + 1, COUNTCOL)
    Set ItersRng = FilterRng.Columns(ITERPOS).Offset(1, 0).Resize(pCountRow, 1)

    Debug.Print IterRng.Address 'returns $B$2:$B$281

    For Each r In IterRng

        Debug.Print r.Address 'returns $B$2:$B$281

    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

missed an "s" off the variable?

```
For Each r In IterRng
```

should be

```
For Each r In ItersRng
```

Apart from the the code is working here

Comment: A perfect example of why putting `Option Explicit` at the top of each module is a good idea - in the VBE window select Tools ~ Options ~ Editor Tab ~ Tick 'Require Variable Declaration'.

Comment: Thanks I actually do use Option Explicit. In the "IterRng" was a typo I made when posting to StackOverflow. Any other ideas? I'm convinced it's related to when I made a class module get property called "Range". But I've since removed that property and even deleted the entire class module even.

Comment: I manually set itersrng to $B$2:$B$281 and it was printing the correct ranges here. Have you tried on a blank new sheet?